# Android Parse- accessing tables through pointers

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to access a table through parse on android. Lets say I have a table animals and animals has a column dog. The entries on column dog are pointers to a dog table. How can I access all rows in the bull dog table so I can check for a particular column in the bull dog table?

Comment: pl share parse database Snap for more understand.